# How do I substring this array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a char array that takes in a binary string of length n. It can only have 0s and 1s.

What I want to do is, I want to make a string array and store the first 2 values of the char array array jointly to the 1st index of this string array.

For example -

```
11011101
```

Is my char array. I want to convert it to an array that would be like -

```
newArray[0] = 11;
newArray[1] = 01;
newArray[2] = 11;
newArray[3] = 01;
```

So basically I just want to split every 2 integers and save them to the newArray in this manner.

My problem is

```
for (int j = 0; j < binaryString.length; j++) {
        lookUp[j] = binaryString.toString().substring(j, j+1);
    }
```

Which is just giving me the memory locations of the indexes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do something like this to get a string from the chars, the rest you can probably figure out already :) String s = "" + binaryString[j] + binaryString[j + 1];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do using [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

This code:

```
char[] cArray = {'1','1','0','1','1','1','0','1'};
String arrayAsString = new String(cArray);
String[] stringArray = arrayAsString.split("(?<=\\G..)");
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(stringArray));
```

Prints this:

```
[11, 01, 11, 01]
```